# HTML5 Canvas анимация

Tags: javascript, html5, анимация, canvas

Возникла такая трудность вывожу на экран(в canvas html5) массив объектов, и мне как то надо задать этим объектам разную скорость вращения. Как это верно реализовать?

Вот код:

```
for (var index = 0; index < pipes.length; index++) {
   t_hmeteor = pipes[index].t_y - (pipes[index].w / 2);
   t_wmeteor = pipes[index].t_x - (pipes[index].h / 2);

   ctx.save();
   ctx.translate(t_wmeteor, t_hmeteor);
   ctx.rotate(inRad(i_meteor));
   ctx.drawImage(meteor_sprite, -pipes[index].w / 2, -pipes[index].h / 2, pipes[index].w, pipes[index].h);
   ctx.restore();

   pipes[index].t_x += 1;
   pipes[index].t_y += 1;

   if (pipes[index].t_y == screen_height - 600) {
         pipes.push({
            t_x: Math.floor(Math.random() * screen_width),
            t_y: 0,
            w: 70,
            h: 70
         });
   }
}
```

`i_meteor` - это скорость вращения(увеличение градуса поворота объекта).

После цикла я делаю `i_meteor += 2;`